# How do I create an arbitrary link in YARD documentation?

Tags: ruby, documentation, rdoc, yard

I'm trying to create some links in my YARD documentation.  I can get an HTTP link:

```
# I like {http://stackoverflow.com Stackoverflow}
```

renders as

```
<p>I like <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a></p>
```

But an email link:

```
# You can email the {mailto:bugs@myproject.com bugs} list
```

gives me a warning:

```
[warn]: In file `':: Cannot resolve link to mailto:bugs@myprojectmailto:bugs@myproject.com from text:
```

and  renders as

```
<p>You can email the <tt>bugs</tt> list</p>
```

I've tried the regular RDoc syntax for links:

```
bugs[mailto:bugs@myproject.com]
```

but YARD seems to ignore that.  Does anyone know of a more reliable syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging into YARD's code shows the problem: in
`gems/yard-0.2.3.5/lib/yard` there is the line (73):

```
if name.include?("://")
```

which doesn't allow mailto links. You can replace this line with

```
if name.include?("://") or name.include?("mailto:")
```

and it will work as you want... not exactly ideal, but that's all I've got right now.

Comment: That's exactly what I did on this fork: http://github.com/gcnovus/yard/commit/5a977b03b8f713588703255806853ca492090a56

Answer (score 3):

0.2.3.6 will have this support